# strange question closing (after "leave open")

Tags: support, bug, vote-to-close, review

I just had a look at the close review queue history and noticed something strange:

The question

[Unable to connect to RHEL client release 5.6 (Tikanga)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179999/unable-to-connect-to-rhel-client-release-5-6-tikanga)

is on hold but cuonglm was the last one voting and he voted for "leave open". How can a "leave open" vote close a question? Doesn't make sense to me. If I click on his or my vote (https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/close/75723) then the voting box says only

- cuonglm reviewed this 21 hours ago: Leave Open
- Hauke Laging reviewed this 22 hours ago: Close

But below the question it says:

> put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Anthon, Michael Homer, jasonwryan, Hauke Laging, cuonglm

So even two strange effects: Why are the three other ones not shown in the voting box above?

Comment: The three others may have voted at the question and not in the review queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He voted outside the queue. The "Leave open" review was done at 2015-01-20 09:56:56Z while the last close vote was at 2015-01-20 09:57:17Z. 21 seconds of difference, which is enough to go back, click "link" and vote.

Answer (score 3):

If you visit the question directly and vote (instead of through the review queue), you won't show up as having reviewed it. So that's probably why the three others are not shown.

I would *guess* cuonglm accidentally clicked leave open, then went back to the question to correct his mistake.